# how to know about classes,methods and imports?

Tags: android

I am a computer science undergrad. I am passionate about programming. I studied c and c++ at college. I learned android on my own. i created 2 apps following youtube videos. and then i wrote comments to those code by reading some of the android programming books. i learned so many good stuffs.

now i am trying to create my own app and i have ideas but  do not know how to know about imports,classes and methods that i can use...and i do not know if there are classes,methods that can be use to turn my dream app into reality....how to know about classes,methods,imports!

i know about developer's site but how to use it..i mean how to get things done ..can anyone give  some example?

like i want my splash screen to be there for 10 secs now how to know required imports,classes and methods....i always go crazy over internet and start to search how others have done and imitate it..what is the real way of learning those stuff? 
i am really eager to learn on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking for a superior strategy to help you identify the Classes and methods that you will need to use.  I don't think such a strategy exists, but I would suggest a couple of ideas:

- Get a good textbook on Android app development, and  read the initial chapters, and all later chapters that appear like they might be relevant.  This should give you a start on understanding the APIs.
- Read through the package-level documentation for all of the packages in the libraries ... including the "java" ones.  This will give you an overview of what is available.
- Look for relevant tutorials and example code to read / borrow from.

From there, it is largely a matter of intelligently searching the Android API docs.  In the case of Java SE and EE, the javadocs include indexes of methods and all classes, together with a type hierarchy and a usage index.  I find that searching these using a web browser's page search can be productive.  But the most important technique is intelligent choice of keywords for your searches.  (If your working vocabulary of IT English is not good, this could be a challenge ...)

Comment: ok got it..there is no such way..its from experience then..thanks!

Comment: @silentflutes - ... until someone develops a way to do brain uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started learning how to develop Android apps as well. I learned by reading books and studying [the online Android documentation](http://developer.android.com). [The books from Commons Ware](http://commonsware.com/) are very good. You should also study general Java programming concepts. I recommend [Learning the Java Language] from [Oracle's Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).